# get comments of post on facebook in php via graph

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

i want to get facebook comments on public post via graph.facebook
i want to get the name, the content and the id of the commenter
example of the graph

http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=391265991032089

mycode so far

```
<?php 
   $data = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=391265991032089');
   $json = $data;
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    $comm_no = $obj->391265991032089->{'data'};
    echo("<pre>");
   var_dump($comm_no);
   ?>
```

wich gives me

```
array(25) {
 [0]=>
 object(stdClass)#437 (7) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(31) "337379989797698_337380613130969"
  ["from"]=>
  object(stdClass)#433 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
  string(15) "100002978598053"
  ["name"]=>
    string(28) "Àñä Båñòtá Bãskõtã"
  }
  ["message"]=>
  string(38) "سقفه لاخوكو ابو جبل :D"
  ["can_remove"]=>
  bool(false)
    ["created_time"]=>
     string(24) "2014-12-15T18:58:24+0000"
   ["like_count"]=>
   int(10)
   ["user_likes"]=>
   bool(false)
    }
```

how to stip it down to just show only 
name , message and id

isearched alot and didnt find any thing

Comment: ID: $comm_no[0]->id; Name: $comm_no[0]->name Message: $comm_no[0]->message

Comment: thanks for your replay but i didnt understand where to modifiy the code and if there is a more than one answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is more than an answer then use the following code:

```
<?php 
   $data = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=391265991032089');
   $json = $data;
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    $comm_no = $obj->391265991032089->{'data'};
    foreach($comm_no as $answer_id => $v) {
    echo $v->from->id . '<br />';
    echo $v->from->name. '<br />';
    echo $v->message. '<br />';
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: sorry for the edit i just wanted to give the working code of you posted ,

Comment: no problem, I've just showed you the usage. You can modify it how you wish.